# replace escaped unicode with elisp

Tags: regex, unicode, emacs

By calling google dictionary api in emacs,
    http://www.google.com/dictionary/json?callback=cb&q=word&sl=en&tl=en&restrict=pr%%2Cde&client=te
I can get response like below

```
"entries": [{
    "type": "example",
    "terms": [{
        "type": "text",
        "text": "his grandfather\x27s \x3cem\x3ewords\x3c/em\x3e had been meant kindly",
        "language": "en"
    }]
}]
```

As you can see there are escaped unicode in "text". I want to convert them in function like below.

```
(defun unescape-string (string)
    "Return unescape unicode string"
    ...
)
(unescape-string "his grandfather\x27s \x3cem\x3ewords\x3c/em\x3e")
=> "his grandfathers's <em>words</em>"

(insert #x27)'
(insert #x27)'
(insert #x3c)<
(insert #x3e)>
```

Here's what I tried

- replace-regexp-in-string
- custom replace like http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ElispCookbook#toc33

But, I think I don't know how to replace '\x123' with corresponding unicode into buffer or string.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Seems like the simplest way to do it:

```
(read (princ "\"his grandfather\\x27s \\x3cem\\x3ewords\\x3c/em\\x3e had been meant kindly\""))
;; "his grandfather's ώm>words</em> had been meant kindly"
```

Also it is really interesting that Emacs parses `\x3ce` rather then `\x3c`. I'm not sure if this is a bug or intended behaviour. I always thought it's not supposed to read more then two characters after `x`...

If you still wanted to use `read` + `princ` combination, you'd need to put a backslash to prevent Emacs from parsing more characters, like so: `\x3c\e`. Or here's something quick I could come up with:

```
(defun replace-c-escape-codes (input)
  (replace-regexp-in-string 
   "\\\\x[[:xdigit:]][[:xdigit:]]"
   (lambda (match)
     (make-string 1 (string-to-number (substring match 2) 16)))
   input))

(replace-c-escape-codes "his grandfather\\x27s \\x3cem\\x3ewords\\x3c/em\\x3e")
"his grandfather's <em>words</em>"
```